# Client management page on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I would like to know what is the best way to create a custom page for my client where he can update is content by himself, the simpliest way possible for him, without even entering drupal management.

I would like to create a page with different dropdown list where he can't update a table on a page, only by selecting an item in those and add other dropdown list as well.

For example: he logs in a custom page
 Theres a list with different kind of fruits, he choose banana and it automaticaly update a page table and update it with banana.

After that he could also create a new drop down list of vegetables for example, and add different kind in it so he can use it to update the site later. All that done with ajax as well.

I'm very new to drupal and have a couple of php notions, but i don't know where to start, would it be in CCK, Views or Form Api or the three at the same time?

Or is there a module out there doing that kind of thing?

English is not my primary language, so sorry if it isn't very clear.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is CCK module. You can create a CCK content type and have a field within it called fruits. From the admin interface you can decide what are the values that should be in the dropdown.

You can give the client permission to create a node of the content type. If you think he should be able to edit only the drop down values, make sure you give him the permission to only that field.

You can create a listing page using http://drupal.org/project/views or you can also consider using
http://drupal.org/project/editview

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and try using the "modify node fields" feature which will allow you to perform bulk operations on node fields displayed in a view and then look into roles & permissions which will help you restrict viewing the "View" by role.